# Styled-components how to display an icon

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the following imports, but not sure how to display the `MyIcon` using **styled-components**, can somebody give some suggestions please, I've looked at other answers but still can't figure it out

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import MyIcon from 'material-design-icons/action/svg/production/ic_favorite_48px.svg';
```

**Edit: It works if I link in material icons stylesheet in my HTML**

*HTML:*

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

*JS:*

```
const MaterialIcon = (props) => (
  <i className={`material-icons ${props.className}`}>account_balance</i>
);

const Icon = styled(MaterialIcon)`
  font-size: 50px;
`;

...
render() {
  return (
    <Icon /> // works
  );
}
```

**But** I don't want to import the whole stylesheet, I want to make use of the  explicit `MyIcon` import?

Answer (score 0):

It’d maybe be easier to use a prebuilt library for React that doesn’t require you to include a Stylesheet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons-react

There are a couple that don’t add an entire Stylesheet programmatically.

Alternatively you could use SVGs and turn them into React components with projects like “svgr”